# iphone sqlite3 UPDATE with LIMIT and OFFSET clause

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Does anyone know if the LIMIT and OFFSET clause work when using the UPDATE statement on iphone. on the sqlite3 website it says

> "if SQLite is built with the SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time option then the syntax of the UPDATE statement is extended with optional ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses.."

if not, can it be enabled?

I'm using `"UPDATE TESTDATA SET VAR = 1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1"`

but i get an error: near "LIMIT": syntax error

I can get LIMIT and OFFSET clause to work on a SELECT statement.

Are there any other ways around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like those only make sense in a SELECT statement. If you want to restrict the rows updated in an UPDATE statement, you should add a WHERE clause.